# How to find a function that meets a given condition?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose I want to find a function $f$ that meets the following condition:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} . \dfrac{x_i}{f} = c$

where $f$ is a function of $x_i$.

What is a systematic way to answer this question? The answer given is $f(x_i)=Ax_i^c$, where $A$ is a positive constant.

My own answer was $f(x_i)=x_i^c$ which I arrived at by trial and error as follows:

> First, I realised that the partial derivative will need to have a $c$ so that I am left with it after I somehow cancel out $\dfrac{x_i}{f}$.
>
> Then, to cancel the $x_i$ in $\dfrac{x_i}{f}$, the partial derivative will need to have $x_i^{-1}$.
>
> So far I have:
>
> $cx_i^{-1}$
>
> Which reminds me of the product rule. Since $c$ is a constant, the partial derivative should be:
>
> $cx_i^{c-1}$
>
> So the function $f(x_i)$ is $f(x_i)=x_i^c$. I don't know where to get the $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

Let's assume that $f=f(x_{i})$, such that we can write:

${\frac{x}{f}}{\frac{df}{dx}}=c$

Now we can see that

${\frac{df}{dx}}=c{\frac{f}{x}}$

${\frac{df}{f}}=c{\frac{dx}{x}}$

Integrating we have

${\ln}f=c{\ln}x+{\alpha}$,

where ${\alpha}$ is a constant that can the represented by ${\ln}{\bf{A}}$. So we proceed

${\ln}f=c{\ln}x+{\ln}{\bf{A}}$

${\ln}f={\ln}({x^{c}{\bf{A}}})$

$f=({x^{c}{\bf{A}}})$

Comment: ${\alpha}$ is an integration constant, and to proceed to the end we use only the logarithm properties.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure on how to justify the manipulations to reach ${\frac{df}{f}}=c{\frac{dx}{x}}$. Could you please provide more details? As I recall, you can't separate out the numerator and denominator in $\frac{df}{dx}$, can you? I've never seen $\frac{df}{f}$ before..what does it mean?. Also, why $\ln$?

Comment: If $f$ only depends on $x$ then you can split it up and integrate both sides by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Finally, Poli used the fact that $\int\frac{dx}x=\ln x$ (plus a constant of course).